# How to convert lodash function to ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

How can I convert my current Lodash function?

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export const paginate = (items, pageNumber, pageSize) => {
    const startIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

    return _(items)
        .slice(startIndex)
        .take(pageSize)
        .value();
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore

Comment: You can have a look at Lodash's source code.

Comment: Can u make the question more clear?

Comment: How? Grab the documentation, read what the methods are doing, find the vanilla JS counterpart.

Comment: Uh... this seems like a roundabout way to avoid using a bog standard [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: what is ".take" in vanilla JS?

Comment: @Galanthus `.slice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for the conversion but you also never needed anything else in lodash either:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

const paginate = (items, pageNumber, pageSize) => {
  const startIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
  return items.slice(startIndex, startIndex + pageSize)
};

console.log(paginate(arr, 1, 2))
console.log(paginate(arr, 2, 2))
console.log(paginate(arr, 3, 2))
console.log(paginate(arr, 1, 3))
console.log(paginate(arr, 2, 3))
```

You could have just used `_.slice` in lodash:

```
return _.slice(items, startIndex, startIndex + pageSize)
```